# Events not showing on full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

the calendar shows the resources

[image: the calendar shows the resources]

Here is the code that generates the calendar

```
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('icalendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                timeZone: 'UTC',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'today prev,next',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'resourceTimelineDay resourceTimeline2Day resourceTimeline3Day'
                },
                footerToolbar: {
                    left: 'today prev,next resourceTimelineDay resourceTimeline2Day resourceTimeline3Day',
                    center: '',
                    right: ''
                },
                initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
                resourceAreaWidth: '15%',
                slotMinTime: '08:00',
                slotMaxTime: '21:00',
                slotDuration: '00:20:00',
                resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Inspection Calendar',
                resources: resources,
                events: events,
                resourceLabelDidMount: function (arg) {
                    arg.el.style.background = arg.resource.extendedProps.color;
                },
            })
            calendar.render();

        });
```

I see the json in the console, first array is the resource that shows and the second array is the events

[image: json in console]

Does anyone know why this would be invalid and not show the event?

I am super confused

Comment: adding ur code helps us to look into the issue

Comment: You're looking at November 5th, and the event's date is November 4th...

Comment: That makes sense, thanks

Comment: So that's all it was? Please double check things more carefully in future... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was the date didn't match what i was looking for